# How to subtract two varchar columns that contain time value as input

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am trying to calculate the difference between two varchar columns to calculate the no. of hours or no. of minutes. But just wondering how can I do it. I tried using TO_DATE,TO_TIMESTAMP functions to convert the varchar columns into datetime/timestamp but they didn't help and then tried the subtraction. Can anybody share some inputs how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

My input data looks like this.

```
Col1       Col2
'7:00 AM'  '7:59 PM'

Output :-
779
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ( TO_DATE( Col2, 'HH12:MI AM' ) - TO_DATE( Col1, 'HH12:MI AM' ) ) * 24 * 60
         AS minutes_difference
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
MINUTES_DIFFERENCE
------------------
               779
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values to date/times using `to_date()`.  This should work:

```
select (to_date(col2, 'HH:MI AM') - to_date(col1, 'HH:MI AM')) * 24 * 60 as minutes
```

Comment: The input column is varchar2

Comment: @Teja . . . That should be `to_date()`.