# Subtract substring days from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

[image: a]

I'm trying to come up with a `Select` statement that would return the `DATE` column minus the number of days in the `DAYS` column.

This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, -+(REPLACE(ISNULL(DAYS,0), 'DAYS', '')), DATE) 
FROM
    T
```

It throws an error

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for minus operator

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "-+" before the `REPLACE`?

Comment: [Subtract two dates stored as varchar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/132391/141074), [convert varchar to date and subtract it from another date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44637627/608639), [How to subtract two varchar columns that contain time value as input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43443421/608639), [SQL subtract date as varchar site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+subtract+date+as+varchar+site%3Astackoverflow.com), etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
dateadd(day, -1*convert(int, coalesce(replace([DAYS], ' days', ''),'0')), [DATE])
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
DECLARE
       @Days VARCHAR(25) = '23 DAYS',
       @Date DATE = '2018-10-23';

SELECT DATEADD(Day, - CAST(REPLACE(@Days , 'DAYS', '') AS INT), @Date )
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012+

```
SELECT DATEADD(Day, - ISNULL(TRY_CAST(REPLACE(@Days , 'DAYS', '') AS INT), 0), @Date )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DATEADD` function expects an integer for its second parameter argument.

By REPLACING 'DAYS' with an empty string, you are still left with a `varchar` containing a number and the blank space that was between that number and the word "DAYS".

`RTRIM` this result and `CAST` it as an `Integer`, and you should be good to go.

Oh, and you also need to put `,DATE` inside the `DATEADD()`'s parenthesis.

Comment: **[Does the blank space really matter?](https://rextester.com/OWRBN5153)**

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the number, cast it to integer as negative and use dateadd like below:

```
SELECT dateadd(DAY,cast('-'+substring([DAYS], 1,charindex(' ',[DAYS])) as int),[DATE])
FROM T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

Use `CHARINDEX` to get the number of days and convert to `int` 
and then `minus` it from `date` column

```
select DATEADD(DAY,-CAST(SUBSTRING(days,1,CHARINDEX(' ',days)) AS INT),DATE),* from #table
```